# LEFT JOIN with SUM not working

Tags: php, mysql, sum, left-join

hoping I could get a hand with a LEFT JOIN + SUM issue I'm having.

The background: I'm building a wee finance system and want to calculate the value of all invoices within a given month (blank months = null). I have two tables:

tsm_finance_calendar - Containing 'months'.
tsm_finance_invoices - Contains details of each invoice.

My query:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT tsm_finance_calendar.month,
                 SUM(tsm_finance_invoices.totalBilled)
          FROM tsm_finance_calendar
          LEFT JOIN tsm_finance_invoices
              ON tsm_finance_calendar.month = tsm_finance_invoices.month
          GROUP BY tsm_finance_calendar.month
          ORDER BY 'id'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['month']. " - $". $row['SUM(totalBilled'];
echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Output is on the right track (Month - $**Blank**) but lacks the result of the sum.

Any help gets a giant high-five :)

Thanks,
RR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `as` keyword in query

```
$query = "SELECT tsm_finance_calendar.month, SUM(tsm_finance_invoices.totalBilled) as sum FROM tsm_finance_calendar LEFT JOIN tsm_finance_invoices ON tsm_finance_calendar.month = tsm_finance_invoices.month GROUP BY tsm_finance_calendar.month ORDER BY 'id'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['month']. " - $". $row['sum'];
echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$row["month"]-$row["SUM(totalBilled)"]`

and you forgot to close a paren                        ^

Answer (score 0):

Did u miss a closing parenthesis in `'SUM(totalBilled'` there?

```
echo $row['month']. " - $". $row['SUM(totalBilled'];
```

And I wonder why you need a JOIN there if both the month field of tsm_finance_invoices is having similar values as tsm_finance_calendar.month ?